Why will the rule with `ln` in script be triggered even if I didn't change any of the code in Snakemake?
Snakemake version:
From 8.0.0 to 8.25.0
Snakefile
rule link:
    input:
        "a"
    output:
        "b"
    script:
        "link.py"

link.py:
from snakemake.shell import shell

cmd = f"""
ln -s {snakemake.input} {snakemake.output}
"""
shell(cmd)

Unexpected behavior
The first run is ok:
❯ snakemake -c1 link
Assuming unrestricted shared filesystem usage.
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job stats:
job      count
-----  -------
link         1
total        1

Select jobs to execute...
Execute 1 jobs...

[Wed Oct 30 14:34:35 2024]
localrule link:
    input: a
    output: b
    jobid: 0
    reason: Missing output files: b
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

[Wed Oct 30 14:34:36 2024]
Finished job 0.
1 of 1 steps (100%) done
Complete log: .snakemake/log/2024-10-30T143435.882631.snakemake.log

Then run again:
❯ snakemake -c1 link
.....
[Wed Oct 30 14:34:37 2024]
localrule link:
    input: a
    output: b
    jobid: 0
    reason: Code has changed since last execution   # Notice here.
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp
.....

But I didn't make any changes.
Expected behavior

If I use shell instead of script, it works well:

Snakefile:
rule link:
    input:
        "a"
    output:
        "b"
    shell:
        "ln -s {input} {output}"
    # script:
    #     "link.py"

Log:
❯ snakemake -c1 link
.....
[Wed Oct 30 14:40:32 2024]
localrule link:
    input: a
    output: b
    jobid: 0
    reason: Missing output files: b
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp
.....

❯ snakemake -c1 link
Building DAG of jobs...
Nothing to be done (all requested files are present and up to date).


If I don't use ln, but other command, it works well:

link.py:
from snakemake.shell import shell

cmd = f"""
echo "Input is {snakemake.input}, output is  {snakemake.output}"
cat {snakemake.input} > {snakemake.output}
"""
shell(cmd)

Log:
❯ snakemake -c1 link
.....
[Wed Oct 30 14:44:10 2024]
localrule link:
    input: a
    output: b
    jobid: 0
    reason: Missing output files: b
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

Input is a, output is  b
[Wed Oct 30 14:44:10 2024]
Finished job 0.
1 of 1 steps (100%) done
Complete log: .snakemake/log/2024-10-30T144410.809273.snakemake.log

❯ snakemake -c1 link
Building DAG of jobs...
Nothing to be done (all requested files are present and up to date).

Use case
The paths of input are ususally very long, I would like to create a symlink to access it more conviently. I can use --rerun-triggers mtime to prevent the trigger, but I'm curious why it it triggered?

I can't seem to recreate this on snakemake 8.25.1 on mac OSX 13.4.1. Copying your minimal example, I touch "a" so link has an input, then the first run runs fine. On second run nothing to be done is reported.

Hmmm....what you have in link.py is not typical python. Try import os; os.system(cmd) where the semi-colon will be replaced by putting those two code parts on separate lines.  I don't think that import you have of shell is advised. So it may make sense it cannot sort what is going on and acting weird.
